# React app using Vite has blank white screen when i open in localhost

Tags: reactjs, localhost, vite

Can anyone help? I have built a react app using vite which im ready to deploy. I can see my app when I run 'npm run dev' in the terminal obviously but when i try to run in the browser through locahost its just a blank white screen. I dont want to deploy for this to be the case

So an example when i open the browser and have the folder URL in the bar http://localhost/F1-Hybrid-Data/f1-app/

Its just a blank white screen. No console errors or anything

Comment: What is the folder url?. Hope you have defined Routes. I think NextJs has that feature, where it can route based on your project folder structure. In Vite, if your are using with React, you have to define Routes or have a single page application